# Increasing title spacing after bibliography heading - natbib package - memoir class

Tags: spacing, bibliographies, natbib

I am trying to add a 2 double space after the heading Bibliography for my thesis. I have tried several solutions and they all fail. the permeable is as follow and I am using natbib library. 
any help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[labelsep=space]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}

\begin{document}
% thesis stuff

\bibliography{bibs}
\end{document}
```

the content of bibs.bib file is as follow:

```
@article{panayi_schock_chui_ejakov_2006, title={Parameterization and FEA  Approach for the Assessment of Piston Characteristics}, DOI={10.4271/2006-01-0429}, journal={SAE Technical Paper Series}, author={Panayi, Andreas and Schock, Harold and Chui, Boon-Keat and Ejakov, Mikhail}, year={2006}, month={3}}
```

I found the following but this changes the title text and format. I can not figure out where to modify to add additional space after the title (bibliography)

```
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\refname%
  \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\refname}{\MakeUppercase\refname}%
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist}
\makeatother
```

the marked space is currently one space and would lie to increase it to double space.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your example compilable (provide an example bib file) and minimal (remove all unnecessary packages).

Comment: Thank you Texnician. I have included the unnecessary packages so that if a new package could be used to solve my issue; it is compatible with the ones that are currently in use. I have also edited the original post to include the bib file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could (mis)use the `\bibpreamble` to add any space you want between the title and the content of the bibliography.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\usepackage[numbers,sort&compress]{natbib}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{panayi_schock_chui_ejakov_2006, 
    title={Parameterization and FEA  Approach for the Assessment of Piston Characteristics}, 
    DOI={10.4271/2006-01-0429}, 
    journal={SAE Technical Paper Series}, 
    author={Panayi, Andreas and Schock, Harold and Chui, Boon-Keat and Ejakov, Mikhail}, 
    year={2006}, 
    month={3}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\renewcommand{\bibpreamble}{\vskip3cm}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. That solved my problem.

Comment: @merinadica You're welcome!